# .NET core JWT authorization failed?

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, .net-core, jwt

I'm trying to get JWT working here, the token is successfully received on my client end after login but when I request user info at the /info route, the authorization fails. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

I get the error:

```
Route matched with {action = "GetInfo", controller = "Accounts", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[ProjectConker.Controllers.AccountsInfo] GetInfo() on controller ProjectConker.Controllers.AccountsController (ProjectConker).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
Authorization failed.
```

This is where the token is issued.

```
        [HttpPost("login")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]LoginInfo credentials)
        {
            if (credentials == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid client request");
            }

            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(credentials.Username);
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, 
            credentials.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("**********"));
                var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);


                var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "http://localhost:5000",
                    audience: "http://localhost:5000",

                    claims: new List<Claim>(){
                        new Claim("username", credentials.Username)
                     },

                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                    signingCredentials: signinCredentials
                );

                var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
                return Ok(new { Token = tokenString, UserName = user.UserName });
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
```

Save token to local storage

```
    public Login(loginForm : ILoginForm) : Observable<ILoginForm>
    {
        return this.http.post<ILoginForm>(this.accountsUrl + "/login", loginForm, httpOptions)
        .pipe(map<any, any>((data, index) => {
            localStorage.setItem("auth_token", data.token);
            this.username = data.username;
            this.loggedIn = true;

            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }));
    }
```

Gets user information

```
    public GetAccountInfo() : Observable<any>
    {
        httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('auth_token'));
        return this.http.get(this.accountsUrl + "/info", httpOptions);
    }
```

returns user info, but authorization fails here

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("info")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

    public async Task<AccountsInfo> GetInfo()
    {

         var usernameClaim = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "username");
         Console.WriteLine(usernameClaim.Value, ConsoleColor.Red);

         var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(usernameClaim.Value);


         return new AccountsInfo{ DisplayName = user.UserName };
     }
```

My startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
                services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                        ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                        ValidAudience = "http://localhost:5000",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))
                    };
                });

            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", 
            builder => 
            {
                builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                       .WithOrigins("*")
                       .AllowCredentials();
            }));

            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();

            services.AddDbContext<ConkerDbContext>(
    options => options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ConkerDbContext>();

            services.AddScoped<SearchEngine>();
            services.AddTransient<RoadmapService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/api/chat");
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Angular's HttpHeaders are [immutable](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders), you can't just use `httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('auth_token'));`, because it would have no effect on the original object.

First thing is the header is invalid, use the Bearer method provided by Ashique, then your GetAccountInfo call would look like this:

```js
public GetAccountInfo() : Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('auth_token')});
    return this.http.get(this.accountsUrl + "/info", {headers});
}
```

Here I assumed that you don't have other HttpOptions set, so I'm just passing the header to the HttpClient. Try it this way and let us know if it's still not working.

Comment: OOOOH, THANKS THAT WAS IT

Answer (score 2):

The default way to add authorization header in HTTP request for ASP.NET core token authentication is to add **Bearer** before the token. So the code should be like this-

```
httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('auth_token'));
```

You can override the default behavior to remove the need of **Bearer**.
Please read the below post to help understand the reason for using bearer before token.
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Bearer-required-before-the-token-in-Authorization-header-in-a-HTTP-request

Also try this,

```
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds,
                IssuedAt = DateTime.Now,
                NotBefore = DateTime.Now
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
```

What i mean is instead of creating a new JWTSecurityToken, Create a SecuritTokenDescriptor, instead of using function WriteToken, use CreateToken. I have used JWT in this way and it worked.

Comment: I still get the same unauthorized error after doing so. But good to know that has to be there.

Answer (score 1):

In the login end point where you create the token you are using key "**********" and in the Setup class you are using key "superSecretKey@345" , this is the problem , the authentication middleware is trying to validate the incoming JWT tokens with key different from the key used to issue the token , you have to use the same key for both issuing and validating , also put the key in somewhere else like "appsettings" to avoid this conflict

```
var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("**********"));
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))
```

Comment: My bad for the inconsistency, but I forgot to asterisize the second one for confidentiality.